# How to properly delete custom post type posts programmatically

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end, wp-delete-post

I created a new custom post type that users can add new post from frontend and it works as desired. Now, I´m trying to add a button to delete. This is the code triggered by the button:

```
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
        $main_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
        wp_delete_attachment( $main_image_id , true );
    }
    if( get_post_meta( $post_id , 'token_personagem' , true ) ) {
        $token_id = get_post_meta( $post_id , 'token_personagem' , true );
        wp_delete_attachment( $token_id , true );
    }
    wp_delete_post( $post_id );
    wp_redirect( $url );
```

Everything seems to work as I wanted (post thumb is deleted, second image is deleted, post is deleted and user is redirected), but an error comes up on debug.log which says:

```
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() Z:\WP-DesktopServer\forjadosmestres.dev.cc\index.php:0
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP   2. require() Z:\WP-DesktopServer\forjadosmestres.dev.cc\index.php:17
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP   3. require_once() Z:\WP-DesktopServer\forjadosmestres.dev.cc\wp-blog-header.php:19
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP   4. include() Z:\WP-DesktopServer\forjadosmestres.dev.cc\wp-includes\template-loader.php:106
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP   5. comments_template() Z:\WP-DesktopServer\forjadosmestres.dev.cc\wp-content\themes\square-child\single-personagem.php:28
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP   6. require() Z:\WP-DesktopServer\forjadosmestres.dev.cc\wp-includes\comment-template.php:1556
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP   7. comment_form() Z:\WP-DesktopServer\forjadosmestres.dev.cc\wp-content\themes\square\comments.php:78
[16-May-2021 23:13:34 UTC] PHP   8. comments_open() Z:\WP-DesktopServer\forjadosmestres.dev.cc\wp-includes\comment-template.php:2327
```

How can I delete custom post type posts without that error? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the problem. Since the wp_delete_post was before the redirect, WordPress tried to reload an inexistent page (and comments, since they are deleted automaticaly with the command) and that generated the error.

The new code is as such and it's not generating errors:

```
        if( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ) {
            $imagem_principal_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
            wp_delete_attachment( $imagem_principal_id , true );
        }
        if( get_post_meta( $post_id , 'token_personagem' , true ) ) {
            $token_id = get_post_meta( $post_id , 'token_personagem' , true );
            wp_delete_attachment( $token_id , true );
        }
        wp_redirect( $url );
        wp_delete_post( $post_id );
        exit;
```

Also, you may notice I added `exit` to the code. That is to follow guidelines [in here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/).